# Regarding Time complexity of program

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

I have done question in one of competitive exam but I am struggling to find out the **time complexity** of program i.e whether it is **O(n) or O(n^2)** in python 3.can any one help me.

I asked one of my friends some of them told it is O(n),and some of them told it is O(n^2) so I am totally get confused with there answers.

```
s = input() #reading base string
b = input() #reading reference string
for i in s:
    if i in b:
        print(i, end='')
```

Sample Input:

```
 polikujmnhytgbvfredcxswqaz  #base string
 abcd  #refernce string
```

Sample output:

```
 bdca
```

Comment: What is `n`?  Your code scales according to two values `len(s)` and `len(b)`.  Once you start thinking of it like that, it should be more clear that your code is `O(len(s)*len(b))`

Comment: You got useful answers here. Why don't you mark an answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misconception here, which is common among beginners in my experience, is that you can only have one variable in your big-O notation. This seems to happensbecause most introductory examples are shown with a single input. When you have multiple independent inputs, you can have multiple variables, since the complexity will scale independently when either input changes.

A ubiquitous example of this is graphs. Graphs have nodes and edges. The number of nodes might set an upper bound on the number of edges, but the two are really quite independent. Most graph algorithms are therefore analyzed in terms of `V` and `E`, rather than a single variable `N`.

What this means for you is that you have two independent quantities. Let's say `S = len(s)` and `B = len(b)`. The outer loop performs `S` iterations. The operator `in b` performs `B` operations in the worst case. If you assume that `print` runs in constant time for a single character, the result is `O(S * B)`.

Answer (score 0):

Where

`n = len(s)
 m = len(b)`

your code will scale with time complexity

```
O(m*n)
```

Since in the worst case you loop through the whole base string and perform `m` maximum constant time if operations. N is often used as a placeholder in theory but has no meaning regarding your code.